# Angular directive cause org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException

Tags: angularjs, spring, thymeleaf

I use `spring 4.2.5`,`thymeleaf 2.1.4`.The problem is that when I ues `Angular's directive`  in `Html`,will cause an Exception.

`org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException`

Html code below

```
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" 
ng-minlength="6" ensure-same ng-required="true" required/>
```

The probelm is `ng-minlength`,`ensure-same` and `required`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data-ng-minlength="6" and required="required".

You need to add 'data-' before your angular directives. By default angular finds both with and without the data prefix and the data prefix is the html standard for custom attributes.

By the way I highly suggest you not to mix angular and tymeleaf if not absolutely mandatory. So much easier to have your static assets served by something else than spring (webserver/cdn) and let spring only serve a json rest api for angular to access.